# How can I assure cohesion in Hibernate entity-relations?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, entity

So, I am currently testing Spring Boot and have created a project that manages projects, users, and tasks. For my database design, I have chosen a many-to-many relationship between users and projects (and between users and tasks as well). I have created a relation table to store the relationship between userId and projectId. I have mapped all the entities and everything seemed fine. However, a friend of mine mentioned that the entity mapping should follow the SOLID principles and that it breaks cohesion.

The mapping of projects to users looks like this:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "userproject",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "projectid"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid"))
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

And the mapping of users to projects looks like this:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
private List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
```

The actual problem is that the Project entity has a list of all users, which in turn have a list of all projects, which have a list of users, and so on.

I have tried to only save the ID in the object, but that didn't work out as expected. I have also tried to write custom repository methods to make CRUD operations on the relationship table, but I need a relationship in the first place.

Is there a good solution for this problem, and is it even necessary? I have never used Hibernate otherwise.